# JSON decode foreach -> only delivery 1 row

Tags: php, arrays, json

my code only delivery 1 row. The first. This JSON contain 3000 rows.

Does anyone know why?
Thanks!

```
if (!empty($_GET["cuit"])){

    $cuit = $_GET["cuit"];
    $directorioDocs = 'data/docs/';
    $data = file_get_contents("data/data.json");
    $proveedores = json_decode($data, true);

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($proveedores as $proveedor) {

        if ($cuit == $proveedor[$i]['cuit']) {
            $proveedorArray = array(
                "cuit" => $proveedor[$i]['cuit'],
            );


        }
        else {$proveedorArray = array("Data" => "Debe ingresar un cuit");
        }
        $i = $i + 1;

    }

    echo json_encode($proveedorArray);
}
else
{
    $proveedorArray = array("Data" => "Debe ingresar un cuit");
    echo json_encode($proveedorArray);

}
```

Comment: You're creating a new array on each foreach loop. You want to append to an array on each loop instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tell you that the solution was found when analyzing the json

I did it with this tool->

https://jsonlint.com/

I'm missing this->

foreach ($proveedores['data'] as  $proveedor) {

Also remove the index [0] that was already unnecessary

That was it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$proveedorArray = array(
    "cuit" => $proveedor[$i]['cuit'],
);
```

Creates a new array each iteration through the loop. You need to append instead:

```
// assuming each item in the parent array should be another array
$proveedorArray[] = array(
    "cuit" => $proveedor[$i]['cuit'],
);
```

You'll also have to do the same in your `else` case inside the loop.

Comment: I'm still having the same problem. If I use another cuit as a parameter other than the first, it returns" Debe ingresar un cuit""